# Dividing fixnum to few parts in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, fixnum

I have some prices (for example `1000000` and `1000`). Does not matter what kind of price (this is can be `345000` or `532`). I need to divide this price into few parts (`["1", "000", "000"]` or `["345", "000"]`).

How I can do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your example includes `000` which can only be a string (`000` as `Fixnum` is rendered as `0`) you can easily split your numbers in group of 3 digits by doing:

```
num = 10000 # your num
res = num.to_s.reverse.scan(/.{1,3}/m).map(&:reverse).reverse 
# res = ["10", "000"]
```

Otherwise if you want to divide the last `0`s and the rest of the number, you can simply do:

```
num = 10000 # your num
res = [num.to_s.sub(/0+$/, '') ,num.to_s.scan(/0+$/)[0]] 
# res = ["1", "0000"]
```

Comment: Does it work as intended for `1000000`?

Comment: @undur_gongor, the second returns `["1", "000000"]`, so yes. The first returns `["1", "000", "000"]`, which is also *intended*.

Comment: @Jeffrey: ;-) I was trying to find out the intentions of Zhenya.

Comment: Not exactly but you know, this is much better because i can freely operate with the last element. I think I may come in handy in the future.

Comment: @Zhenya, then what do you need exactly? `[1, 000 000]` is not valid Ruby syntax, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: I make mistake in question, sorry. I edited question.

Comment: @Zhenya, you mean `["1", "000", "000"]` or `[1, 0, 0]`?

Comment: `["1", "000", "000"]`

Comment: @Zhenya, then the first should do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take:

```
i = 1000000
i.to_s.reverse.chars.each_slice(3).map(&:reverse).map(&:join).reverse # -> ['1', '000', '000']
```